# En Java:¿Cual es la diferencia entre una variable de tipo int, y una del tipo double?

Tags: java

yo estaba haciendo un programa que intentara calcular pi, pero java me soltó un error:

> Error: possible lossy conversion from double to int

lo resolví cambiando todas mis variables al tipo double, pero me quedó la curiosidad acerca de la diferencia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El tipo `double` es un tipo de datos de coma flotante, es decir, puede almacenar números *reales* con decimales (hasta cierta precisión), tales como `3.1415926537` o `1.0`, mientras que el tipo `int` es un tipo entero y solo puede almacenar números sin decimales, tales como `1`, `2`, `3`, etc.

Es por eso que al asignar un `double` a un `int`, java te alerta. La traducción libre del mensaje sería algo como:

> Error: posible conversión *con pérdida de información* de double a int

Más información en [java Primitive Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) (en inglés)